# How can I specify /usr/local as an install directory during application install on Mac?

Tags: macos, installation, finder

I have an 10.5.8 MacOS, trying to install an application into the directory `/usr/local/`

which I try to specify it, the Finder comes up which doesn't allow me to go to `/usr/local`.

[image]

So I created a link to it, but it grays out the link.

I logged in as Administrator but it still grays out the link.

**How can I get Finder to allow me to select /usr/local as an install directory?**

Comment: An installer package will definitely not allow you to install in `/usr/local`. Can you use the [Suspicious Package](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) Quicklook plugin to see where the installer will put all the files? Maybe it already will install some files in `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer to this:

- in finder
- click on "go"
- type in `/usr`
- drag `local` to sidebar
- then when you are installing, `local` will appear in the sidebar